# Regex needs to skip words in named pattern C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a list of regex patterns I'm looping through, and doing an action if it is successful. Here's what I have now:

```
string csvText = 
  "A Minimum Usage Fee of ten dollars and ninety-nine cents ($10.99) for each Customer ESI ID with electricity consumption less than 1,000 kWh per billing cycle.";

string csvPattern =
  @"A Minimum Usage Fee of (\p{Sc}*(?<cost>\s?\d+[., ]?\d*)) for each Customer ESI ID with electricity consumption (?<comparator>[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+) (?<usage>[0-9, ]+) kWh per billing cycle.";

Regex regex = new Regex(csvPattern);
var match = regex.Match(csvText);
```

However, I have a string that will vary ("ten dollars and ninety-nine cents"), and then the value I want ("10.99"). How do I tell a named regex string to skip those words? I've tried (unsuccessfully) adding a look-behind in the cost group, but it does not match.

Comment: Is regex the best solution to this problem?

Comment: Is that cost format always `$somedigits.somedigits` ?

Comment: No. But it's what production is asking for. @timothyclifford

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cost format is consistent then you don't need  `(\p{Sc}*(?<cost>\s?\d+[., ]?\d*))`.

You should go with `(?<cost>\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`

```
string csvText = "A Minimum Usage Fee of ten dollars and ninety-nine cents ($10.99) for each Customer ESI ID with electricity consumption less than 1,000 kWh per billing cycle.";
        string csvPattern =
            @"A Minimum Usage Fee of [A-Za-z -]+ \((?<cost>\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\) for each Customer ESI ID with electricity consumption (?<comparator>[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+) (?<usage>[0-9, ]+) kWh per billing cycle\.";

    Regex regex = new Regex(csvPattern);
    var match = regex.Match(csvText);
```

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dZ1gR9/1)**

Comment: Thank you, my friend. May you find a random $5 today.

Comment: @sparkysword: Shall I give you my Paypal ID ? ☺☻